# Node.js read and write stream to the same file at the same time

Tags: node.js, file, stream, fs, file-descriptor

**TL;DR**

I'm browsing through a number of solutions on `npm` and `github` looking for something that would allow me to `read` and `write` to the same file in two different places at the same time. So far I'm having trouble actually finding anything like this. Is there a module of some sort that will allow that?

**Background**

In essence my requirement is that in a large file I need to, in the following order:

- read
- transform
- write

Ideally the usage would be something like:

```
const fd = fs.open(file, "r+");
const read = createReadStreamSomehowFrom(fd);
const write = createWriteStreamSomehowFrom(fd);

read
   .pipe(new Transform(transform() {...}))
   .pipe(write);
```

I could do that with standard `fs.create[Read/Write]Stream` but there's no way to control the flow of both streams and if my write position goes beyond read position then I'm reading something I just wrote...

The use case is the same as `perl -p -i -e`, read and write to the same file (meaning the same inode) asynchronously and replace the contents without loading everything into memory.

I would expect this a real world use case, yet all implementations I found actually load the whole file into memory and then save it. Am I missing a known module here or is there a need to actually write something like this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hmm... a tough one it seems. :)

So here's for the record - I found no such module and actually discussed this with some people responsible for a nice in-file replacing module. Seeing no way to solve this I decided to write it from scratch and here it is:

- [signicode/rw-stream repo on github](https://github.com/signicode/rw-stream/)
- [rw-stream at npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rw-stream)

The module works on a simple principle that no byte can be written until it has been consumed in the readable stream and it's fairly simple underneath (couple `fs.read/write` ops with keeping eye on the point of read and write).

If you find this useful then I'm happy. :)