# how can I make writable stream from readable stream in NODEJS

Tags: node.js

Here is my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var myreadStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/file.txt');
var mywriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname+'/fuzz.txt');

myreadStream.on('data', (chunk) => console.log("New Chunk Recieved " + chunk));

mywriteStream.write(chunk);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52561735/node-js-read-and-write-stream-to-the-same-file-at-the-same-time there is a same question as you've asked, could be useful, check it !